# Find specific value from database, from VB.net

Tags: sql, database, vb.net, ms-access, data-binding

I want to find a specific value from an Access database. Then manipulate this value as part of validation (weigh a user inputted value against a min and max values in the database)

I can get the data in from the database but I can't seem to fill a data table. I want to user to type in the primary key and then when the button is clicked an SQL statment uses that input to find the value then put that value into a Data Table and spit that value out on a textbox. I figure if I can get it spitting out the right value then I can put the value into a variable that I can manipulate.

I don't need to change the data in the database I just need to collect the values in order to verify user entered data. Here is the code I have so far.

```
 Private Sub btnValidate_Click_1(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnValidate.Click

    Dim ds As New DataSet
    Dim da As OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter

    dbConnect.ConnectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=C:\Users\crabara\Desktop\Project Alpha 3\MDB.accdb;Persist Security Info=False;"
    dbConnect.Open()

    da = New OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter("SELECT MoldVinylWeightMin FROM PROCESS_INFO WHERE PCRNumber =" & txtPcr.Text, dbConnect)

    da.Fill(ds, "MinWeight")


    TextBox1.Text = ds.Tables("MinWeight").Rows(0).Item(0)

End Sub
```

Right now it throws the error "Data type mismatch in criteria expression." Any help would be great, I can't find much info on this.

Comment: This is working code, it will take in the primary key from the user and find the specific value in the database. Then print out that value onto the from via textbox.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If PRCNumber is a numeric type in the database you will not need to quote it

```
so:  PCRNumber ='" & txtPcr.Text & "'"
  becomes 
 PCRNumber = " & txtPcr.Text
```

Comment: Yes PCRNumber is a numeric type.

Comment: It's working, that was so stupid. Thanks man, I assume that instead of a textbox I can just dump it into a variable correct?

Comment: to be safe you should check the textbox for numeric input before assembling the SELECT statement, but once validated (e.g. using If IsNumeric(txtPrcr.Text) = False Then ... [error message to user]) its fine to use textbox.Text

Comment: Thanks, I'm a CS intern learning all this on the fly in real world application. I should pay my tuition to forums, because without people like you I'd be in manual labor!